# How to get raspi-config on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: raspi-config

Is using **raspi-config** on Ubuntu an anti-pattern or there's an equivalent package made just for Ubuntu?

I'd like to use it to easily control OverlayFS for example. Is this possible with Ubuntu on RPi 4?

Answer (score 7):

`raspi-config` is a simple (if long and involved) shell script to configure Pi hardware and Raspbian settings. It is just a front end to the underlying system commands.

As Ubuntu (which doesn't even have a supported Desktop OS) uses different networking, kernel and many other packages it would need a Ubuntu specific version (there was a version for Ubuntu MATE 16.04). Canonical, in its infinite wisdom, has not provided an equivalent.

It would be feasible for a Ubuntu user to write a version for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [following script](https://github.com/EmilGus/install_raspi-config/) to install `raspi-config` to any Debian like OS.

```
wget https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-config/raspi-config_20200601_all.deb -P /tmp
sudo apt-get install libnewt0.52 whiptail parted triggerhappy lua5.1 alsa-utils -y
# Auto install dependancies on eg. ubuntu server on RPI
sudo apt-get install -fy
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/raspi-config_20200601_all.deb
```

But it couldn't be really useful as said @Milliways because of different OS libs.

Comment: In Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on x86 (Eee PC 900) I only had to `sudo apt install lua5.1` in order to install raspi-config_20210119_all.deb.